# Slider script show different ammount of items on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have a slide script where you can set the ammount of visible images and need to change the ammount when I reach a browser size.

When browser width is smaller than 768px show 4 items.
Is this possible to combine below 2 scripts?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/Q99r3/1/)

**Slider script:**

```
$('.logo-slide').wmuSlider({
    touch: Modernizr.touch,
    animation: 'slide',
    items: 5
});
```

**Browser width script:**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $(".nav-wide").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".nav-wide").show();
    }
});
```

**I try to combine these like below script, but it doesn't work**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.logo-slide').wmuSlider({
            items: 4
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.logo-slide').wmuSlider({
            items: 5
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window.width and resize methods are spot on for detecting the different screen sizes.

The jquery plugin is probably developed to be called only once on page load.

A plugin like this might be a better option where you can have minimum and maximum item numbers?

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ (see // Carousel Options minItems and maxItems)

Comment: will check that out but rather use this script. 
https://github.com/pastawoua/wmuSlider/blob/master/jquery.wmuslider.js

Comment: Carousel With Min & Max Ranges indeed. Guess I will use that script then.

Comment: Its not that perfect when it is scrolling to the next images :( I see half an image.

Comment: it had to do with margins I guess, the only thing it doesn't do correct is slide to the next image, it shows the next "set" of images.. not +1

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS3

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .logo-slide { display: none; }
    }
```